# Why can I not find any Aluminium?

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

I've played a number of matches now on an Earth map in BNW, both with a modded and unmodded version, and for some reason, I never find any aluminium anywhere. I find plenty of Iron, Uranium, Coal and Oil, but I never find any Aluminium spawns. I've tried this on multiple machines, with and without a realistic earth mod, with both Venice, Egypt and America. I always have to resort to the paltry 10 you get from the recycling centers. I have the tech, and I even once took the time to check the entire map after I unlocked satellites, and I still didn't find any.

Is this just a freak coincidence or are there actually documented reasons for this occuring?

Comment: Two reasons shoot in my mind: 1. It is a handmade map and the mapper just didn't like Aluminium. 2. Resources are generated randomly and random may also mean "less than a few". EDIT: If this is a custom map, you may use the map editor to just look where Aluminium should be.

Comment: @Trollwut The realistic map mod is http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77138438. I usually use the huge map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom map you're using has an issue, it doesn't appear to be a problem with the game itself.

https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/discussion/77138438/135508489638009415/